# Fonts in my .css file did not change while I used ID SELECTOR

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, font-size

[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LTfB.jpg)
Hi,guys
I wanna specify a 5

HTML with .css file,which I used ID SELECTOR to make it.
But the size of the fonts didn't change.
(Screenshot uploaded See below:)

```css
#fontsizea{
font-family:Arial;
font-size:1px;
}
#fontsizeb{
font-family:League Gothic;
font-size:2px;
}
#fontsizec{
font-family:Gotham;
font-size:3px;
}
#fontsized{
font-family:Times New Roman;
font-size:5px;
}
#fontsizee{
font-family:Georgia;
font-size:10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
CASE - font-size - px
</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS for CASE - font-size - px CSS.css">
</head>
<body>
<p id="fontsizea">This is a text in 1.0 px .</p><br>
<p id="fontsizeb">This is a text in 2.0 px .</p><br>
<p id="fontsizec">This is a text in 3.0 px .</p><br>
<p id="fontsized">This is a text in 5.0 px .</p><br>
<p id="fontsizee">This is a text in 10.0 px .</p><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Where is wrong?
[image]

Comment: It works fine in the snippet. Do you maybe have some other `font-size` rule that's more specific in your real example?

Comment: The code snippet you have created seems to be working fine. Maybe its because your browser can't render so tiny font? Try a different browser and check.

Comment: Can you share your code or explain more. As you can also see that code snippet working fine. So we can't find the mistake.

Comment: This is all project it is,I opened it in my computer with Microsoft Edge,but it was seem that sizes went in the same.you can see:https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4pHq.jpg

Comment: It is browser problem. then I have fixed it. Thank all of @allguys who concerned my question. 